# What HTML tags to use to describe an image?

Tags: html, tags

My typical image will have an event name (short text), a description text (longer text), and copyright text (short text) below it. I'm looking for the best tag use case. Don't worry about compatibility with older browers. The image will be in a figure tag, so we're talking about content within figcaption here.

Example:

```
-------------------------
- imagine an image here -
-------------------------
Marathon 2013
Some great Marathon 2013 photo of a great runner. This could go on, and on, and on... 
and will span multiple lines most of the time. 
Courtesy of somesite.com
```

I'm currently using cite for event (Marathon 2013) and copyright (Courtesy of somesite.com). I'm thinking of span for the description.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

```
        <figure>
          <img src="image.jpg" alt="image text">
          <figcaption>Some great Marathon 2013 photo of a great runner.
            This could go on, and on, and on... and will span multiple lines most of the time. 
            Courtesy of somesite.com</figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Inside figcaption you can use all tags you want like `<a> or <span>`

and you can use figure for multi images like this

```
        <figure>
          <img src="image.jpg" alt="image text">
          <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image text">
          <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image text">
          <figcaption>Some great Marathon 2013 photo of a great runner.
            This could go on, and on, and on... and will span multiple lines most of the time. 
            Courtesy of somesite.com</figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example +1. Maybe have a cite inside of figcaption for the "this could go on and on" part

Comment: The question is about what tags should be used for the three components within figcaption.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. figure for image. Figcaption containing span / cite sounds good.

Comment: small tag for copyright? Can you explain why it wins over cite?